# How to hide Oracle/Netsuite logo?

Tags: netsuite

Please help I would like to hide the logo from the top left corner, leave only the company logo.

I've tried but I couldn't find any possible solution, any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that is possible, without dynamically editing the DOM.  I can't think of a reason why NetSuite would want to allow people to hide that logo.

Answer (score 0):

I was tired of the NetSuite logo, so I made a free Chrome Extension to hide it and the header section it sits in. If you need the header section, just press Ctrl + Space. Here is a link to the Chrome store.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-focus/dhhnagipehhhighojjmbpjlnejbeodlk